# A bit confused about the "agenda" of a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I wrote a few extensions, most disposable and [one hopefully viable](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skwares/koepapmllfahhfimhhkgfihkjgkndiog?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

I'm still a bit confused about the "agenda", of "schedule" or whatchacallit, i.e. the order in which things happen, and the places where they live.

For example, I am writing a new one that shall do the following :

- a browser action presents the user with a menu of 3 items
- two of those items trigger actions to be executed immediately, while the third lauches a process that is to run undercover for an extended period (namely polling a certain web page at an interval, said web page needing *not* to be loaded in any visible tab or window).

Naturally I'd be tempted to assume that the long-term is to live in the `background.js`.

Now, I understand that the pop-up menu is an HTML document in its own right, living its life in its own bubble. It shall disappear right after the user cliked on an item, thereby taking its context with it to its grave. Right now I'm at a bit of a loss trying to figure out how it can trigger a background process.

Notwithstanding, I don't quite grasp what brings the `background.js` to life, even less so when it is specified as non persistent [as is recommended](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

Naturally, I'll RTFM again, but if you fellows could dumb this down to my poor level of understanding, I'd be so happy ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as you said, you would need to RTFM again..

[Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) runs in the extension process and exists for the lifetime of your extension, until your extension is removed or the browser process terminates.

While [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), what chrome has recommended to use, is loaded only when they are needed. Take a look at [Lifetime part](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#lifetime), the following are some example that will cause the event page to load:

> - The app or extension is first installed or is updated to a new version (in order to [register for events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#registration)).
> - The event page was listening for an event, and the event is dispatched.
> - A content script or other extension [sends a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).
> - Another view in the extension (for example, a popup) calls [runtime.getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage).

As for your question, 'how it can trigger a background process', if there are no events to catch or message to pass, you can just call [runtime.getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) to load the event page.